# Calling a PHP function from an HTML form in the same file

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm trying to execute a PHP function in the same page after the user enters a text and presses a submit button.

The first I think of is using forms. When the user submits a form, a PHP function will be executed in the same page. The user will not be directed to another page. The processing will be done and displayed in the same page (without reloading).

Here is what I reach to:

In the **test.php** file:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()" />
</form>
```

The PHP code [ **`test()` function** ] is ***in the same file*** also:

```
<?php
    function test() {
        echo $_POST["user"]; // Just an example of processing
    }
?>
```

However, I still getting a problem! Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: `onclick=` invokes a Javascript function. Which is probably what you should be using here.

Comment: My processing is more than echoing a text. It can NOT performed using Javascript. It needs PHP

Comment: I think you need learn a bit more about client side and server side languages.  If you need to do this without refreshing you will have implement it in a client side language (eg javascript) or use AJAX to execute the request client side.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This cannot be done in the fashion you are talking about. PHP is *server-side* while *the form* exists on the client-side. You will need to look into using JavaScript and/or Ajax if you don't want to refresh the page.

#### test.php

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax('getResult.php', str, function(result){
            alert(result); // The result variable will contain any text echoed by getResult.php
        }
        return(false);
    });
</script>
```

It will call `getResult.php` and pass the serialized form to it so the PHP can read those values. Anything `getResult.php` echos will be returned to the JavaScript function in the `result` variable back on `test.php` and (in this case) shown in an alert box.

#### getResult.php

```
<?php
    echo "The name you typed is: " . $_REQUEST['user'];
?>
```

**NOTE**

This example uses jQuery, a third-party  JavaScript wrapper. I suggest you first develop a better understanding of how these web technologies work together before complicating things for yourself further.

Comment: I need to execute a PHP code. But also, I need to NOT refresh the page. Does Javascript and/or AJAX provide this?

Comment: You should note in your answer that your example uses jQuery (which might not be a good idea, one should grab the basic knowledge about the Web first).

Answer (score 10):

You have a big misunderstanding of how the web works.

Basically, things happen this way:

- User (well, the browser) requests `test.php` from your server
- On the server, `test.php` runs, everything inside is executed, and a resulting HTML page (which includes your form) will be sent back to browser
- The browser displays the form, the user can interact with it.
- The user submits the form (to the URL defined in `action`, which is the same file in this case), so everything starts from the beginning (except the data in the form will also be sent). New request to the server, PHP runs, etc. That means the page will be refreshed.

You were trying to invoke `test()` from your `onclick` attribute. This technique is used to run a **client-side** script, which is in most cases **Javascript** (code will run on the user's browser). That has nothing to do with **PHP**, which is **server-side**, resides on your server and will only run if a request comes in. Please read [Client-side Versus Server-side Coding](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/923111/Client-side-Versus-Server-side-Coding---Part-1.htm) for example.

If you want to do something without causing a page refresh, you have to use Javascript to send a request in the background to the server, let PHP do what it needs to do, and receive an answer from it. This technique is basically called **AJAX**, and you can find lots of great resources on it using Google (like [Mozilla's amazing tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX)).

Answer (score 6):

Without reloading, using HTML and PHP only it is not possible, but this can be very similar to what you want, but you have to reload:

```
<?php
    function test() {
        echo $_POST["user"];
    }

    if (isset($_POST[])) { // If it is the first time, it does nothing
        test();
    }
?>

<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="test()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a full php script to do what you're describing, though pointless. You need to read up on server-side vs. client-side. PHP can't run on the client-side, you have to use javascript to interact with the server, or put up with a page refresh. If you can't understand that, there is no way you'll be able to use my code (or anyone else's) to your benefit.

The following code performs AJAX call without jQuery, and calls the same script to stream XML to the AJAX. It then inserts your username and a `<br/>` in a div below the user box.

Please go back to learning the basics before trying to pursue something as advanced as AJAX. You'll only be confusing yourself in the end and potentially wasting other people's money.

```
<?php
    function test() {
        header("Content-Type: text/xml");
        echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" standalone=\"yes\"?><user>".$_GET["user"]."</user>"; //output an xml document.
    }
    if(isset($_GET["user"])){
        test();
    } else {
?><html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function do_ajax() {
                if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
                        data=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("user")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                        mydiv = document.getElementById("Test");
                        mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));
                        mydiv.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>?user="+document.getElementById('username').value,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" id="username"/>
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="do_ajax()" />
        </form>
        <div id="Test"></div>
    </body>
</html><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [SAJAX](http://www.modernmethod.com/sajax/) or switch to JavaScript

> Sajax is an open source tool to make
>   programming websites using the Ajax
>   framework — also known as
>   XMLHTTPRequest or remote scripting —
>   as easy as possible. Sajax makes it
>   easy to call PHP, Perl or Python
>   functions from your webpages via
>   JavaScript without performing a
>   browser refresh.

Comment: I need something simpler than this. It looks like so complex !

Comment: @2rk Well, webprogramming is a profession, and not something easy like "hey let's build a website". If you want to create websites, first you have to learn how to do it. And then learn and learn something new every day.

Comment: jQuery is much simpler and can be used easily by novices.

Answer (score 3):

That's now how PHP works. `test()` will execute when the page is loaded, not when the submit button is clicked.

To do this sort of thing, you have to have the `onclick` attribute do an AJAX call to a PHP file.

Comment: Then how to make it the other way? when the button clicked?

Answer (score 3):

in case you don't want to use Ajax , and want your page to reload .

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['user']) {
echo $_POST["user"]; //just an example of processing
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can submit the form without refreshing the page, but to my knowledge it is impossible without using a JavaScript/Ajax call to a PHP script on your server.  The following example uses the [jQuery JavaScript library](http://jquery.com/).

#### HTML

```
<form method = 'post' action = '' id = 'theForm'>
...
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $("#theForm").submit(function() {
        var data = "a=5&b=6&c=7";
        $.ajax({
            url: "path/to/php/file.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(html) {
                .. anything you want to do upon success here ..
                alert(html); // alert the output from the PHP Script
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Upon submission, the anonymous Javascript function will be called, which simply sends a request to your PHP file (which will need to be in a *separate* file, btw). The `data` above needs to be a URL-encoded query string that you want to send to the PHP file (basically all of the current values of the form fields). These will appear to your server-side PHP script in the `$_GET` super global.  An example is below.

```
var data = "a=5&b=6&c=7";
```

If that is your data string, then the PHP script will see this as:

```
echo($_GET['a']); // 5
echo($_GET['b']); // 6
echo($_GET['c']); // 7
```

You, however, will need to construct the data from the form fields as they exist for your form, such as:

```
var data = "user=" + $("#user").val();
```

(You will need to tag each form field with an 'id', the above id is 'user'.)

After the PHP script runs, the `success` function is called, and any and all output produced by the PHP script will be stored in the variable `html`.

```
...
success: function(html) {
    alert(html);
}
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
   $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
   $comment = test_input($_POST["comment"]);
   $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 
   Name: <input type="text" name="name">
   <br><br>
   E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
   <br><br>
   Website: <input type="text" name="website">
   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
   <br><br>
   Gender:
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $website;
echo "<br>";
echo $comment;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way that I use to create submit without loading in a form.

You can use some CSS to stylise the iframe the way you want.

A php result will be loaded into the iframe.

```html
<form method="post" action="test.php" target="view">
  <input type="text" name="anyname" palceholder="Enter your name"/>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
  </form>
<iframe name="view" frameborder="0" style="width:100%">
  </iframe>
```