# Ajax calls a back end PHP script not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I tried the answer from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967322/calling-a-php-function-from-an-html-form-in-the-same-file).  This does not work.  test.php does give me a box to input text with a submit button.  Firefox browser developer console gives me this message before I submit:

"SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

After I typed in a text and submit:

"A form was submitted in the windows-1252 encoding which cannot encode all Unicode characters, so user input may get corrupted. To avoid this problem, the page should be changed so that the form is submitted in the UTF-8 encoding either by changing the encoding of the page itself to UTF-8 or by specifying accept-charset=utf-8 on the form element."

Any suggestions?

test.php has this snippet:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax('getResult.php', str, function(result){
            alert(result); // the result variable will contain any text echoed by getResult.php
        }
        return(false);
    });
</script>
```

getResult.php has this:

```
<?php
    echo "The name you typed is: " . $_REQUEST['user'];
?>
```

Comment: have you checked the console to see what is happening in the response? in developer tools

Comment: @Harry:  There is an additional error: "SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Comment: Right away I notice you are missing a ) in your script.

Comment: @user523234 that's your problem then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you missed a closing bracket here,

```
    $.ajax('getResult.php', str, function(result){
        alert(result); // the result variable will contain any text echoed by getResult.php
    }
     ^ missing );
```

And second, use POST request instead of AJAX, like this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.post('getResult.php', str, function(result){
        alert(result); 
    });
    return(false);
});
```

Or if you want to use AJAX request then do this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'getResult.php',
        cache: 'false',
        data: str,

        success: function(result){
            alert(result)
        }
    });
    return(false);
});
```

Comment: If I put ); per your suggestion, I go t a new error:  ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: @user523234 May be you didn't include jQuery library. Add jQuery library before your script so that $ can be identified, like this: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

Comment: That was the issue and since I was using ssl.  Firefox will block any call not using ssl as well.  https://code.jquery.... will fix.  Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

You should use $_POST['user'] instead $_REQUEST['user'] in your getResult.php code, like this:

```php
<?php
    echo "The name you typed is: " . $_POST['user'];
?>
```

The warning message says that you are not using the appropriate text encoding. Some of the characters you are sending through the form are not in "windows-1252" encoding (Emojis, for example).
I recommend you to change the encoding of your entire website, by setting the encoding metatag inside the head section of your page, and removing other encoding tags you might have:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

But, if you only want to change the encoding in your form, which i don't recommend, use this code:

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post" accept-charset=utf-8>
    <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="enter a text" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax('getResult.php', str, function(result){
            alert(result); // the result variable will contain any text echoed by getResult.php
        }
        return(false);
    });
</script>
```