# Google Drive API Upload / Download - PHP to Client

Tags: php, ajax, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm fairly new to writing in PHP and I've hit a snag while developing a Google Drive connection. I'm trying to create a small widget for a WordPress site wherein users on the site can upload and download files from their Google Drives.

These users are from a closed GSuite Domain and I use a Domain-Wide Service account in order to authenticate and connect to the user's drives.

I am able to connect, retrieve a list of files, and successfully "download" a files contents, though, this download does not actually download a file to the computer, simply returns the contents.

### References:

-Uploading: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

-Downloading: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

-- I need to place a download button on my page which will allow a user to select a file and download it to their computer without saving it on the server. Currently it just returns the content of the file which I can store in a variable, but I do not know how to have a client request it and download it.

I need an upload button as well but I am working on a solution that I believe will work. I've read many different articles suggesting Ajax, Node, etc...

Ajax:
[Calling a PHP function from an HTML form in the same file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967322/calling-a-php-function-from-an-html-form-in-the-same-file)

Upload UI:
https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/cms/create-a-file-uploader-in-wordpress.html

**In my client initialization file:**

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);

$driveService = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
return $driveService;
```

**In the php script that loads the widget on the page:**

```
$drive_connection = getUserGoogleDriveService();
$retrieved_files = array();
$filesList = $drive_connection->files->listFiles();
foreach($filesList->files as $file)
{
    array_push($retrieved_files, array(
        'filename'  =>  $file->name,
        'fileid'    =>  $file->id,
        'file'      =>  $file
    ));
}

$get_specific_file = array_search('example_file_name', 
    array_column($retrieved_files, 'filename'));
```

- Edit: I added my code thus far. This code successfully lets me store and retrieve files from my array for further use. How would I tie this into a client side UI to upload files to the google "create" function.